# Check for difference in i-th bit

Tags: bit-manipulation

For positive integers *a* and *b*, are the following two expressions logically equivalent?

- *a ⊕ b = 2<sup>i</sup>*
- *|a - b| = 2<sup>i</sup>*

Comment: Only if there is indeed just one bit flip. Is that a pre-condition? That's not super clear in this question

Comment: No, that is not a precondition. What would be a counter example that makes one of both true and the other false?

Comment: For example `a = 1, b = 2, i = 0`, then `a ⊕ b = 3` (and therefore not equal to any power of two) but `abs(1 - 2) = 1`

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. Thank you.